# Hiding Label at Runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to hide a label inside a repeater.

```
<td>
   <div>
      <asp:Repeater ID="rpt1" runat="server" 
                    OnItemDataBound="rpt1_ItemDataBound">
            <HeaderTemplate>
               <table>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <div>
                           <label id="lbl1"  runat="server">
                              <b>Project</b>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </HeaderTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
</td>
```

I want to hide Label lbl1 dynamically.

```
protected void rpt1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header)
        {
            //IT COMES HERE
            Label label = e.Item.FindControl("lbl1") as Label;
            label.Visible = false;
            // ERROR: OBJECT REFERENCE NOT SET TO AN INSTANCE OF AN OBJ
        }
    }
```

Here, when I try to debug the code, it comes inside the loop but gives me object reference not set to an instance of an object error.

**UPDATE**

If I Try,

```
  HtmlGenericControl label = e.Item.FindControl("lbl1") as HtmlGenericControl;
            label.Visible = false;
```

It works

Comment: Missing runat=server on the label?

Comment: @KalelWade Still getting the same error.

Comment: when you debug the code on after this line `Label label = e.Item.FindControl("lbl1") as Label;` what is the value of `label` if it's null or empty then you need to add the 'runat="server"` attribute to the `lbl1` object in your aspx markup best to check out the example here on this msdn documentation -https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Comment: It is null, but I added runat="server", still its giving the same error.

Comment: Did you click save and rebuild? Figured I would ask, sometimes those simple things are missed.

Comment: you need to use `<asp:label>` look at the correct answer provided below or read the msdn documentation they provide an exact example.things of this nature should be googled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are talking about td

in your aspx or ascx

```
<td id="tdid" runat="server">
```

code behind

```
HtmlTableCell td=e.Item.FindControl("tdid") as HtmlTableCell ;
```

Answer (score 6):

transform your label to asp:Label with a runat="server"

```
 <asp:label id="lbl1" runat="server">
```

Or keep it as you wrote and add runat="server" and in your codebihind

```
HtmlGenericControl label = e.Item.FindControl("lbl1") as HtmlGenericControl;
```

Comment: I was just about to post the `<asp:Label...>`, beat me to it!

Comment: HtmlGenericControl exists in System.Web.UI.HtmlControls NameSpace

Comment: Thank you, but suppose I want to hide the full td with id = "td1" (see the code), then what should I do ?

Comment: have a look to my second answer and if it helps you mark it as a correct one .

thank you :)

Comment: need double quotes for server tag  like runat="server"

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV. Done again :)

Comment: also make a not if we use  label.Visible = false; in server side then we can't visible it in client side. so it is better to use labelid.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none");

Comment: Ok now it's looks fine

Comment: Yes @ArunprasanthKV , i don't need to generate HTML code client side that's why i used Visibule attribute server side :)

Comment: Ok then i have a doubt , if you don't need to generate HTML code client side then what is the significance of that label ? why we need a label control in that page ??

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV. i m working on a project where webUI control generation depends on user profile (Manager,salesman,account manager...)